# jquery ajax file upload error on MAC safari

Tags: macos, jquery, safari

I am using ajaxfileupload on to upload images, and it works fine in all browsers on my windows system including Safari...however, on MAC Safari, the $_file array is empty. Any ideas how to debug?

I am not pasting any code here because I have no ideas where the error possibly could be. If you can give me some debug suggestions, I'll be glad to share the results.